# TCA ADD wizard in TYPO 9 and 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to update an extension from TYPO3 v7 to v9. In v7 is it possible to add an ADD-Wizard to a select field in the TCA:

```
'wizards' => array(
    '_PADDING'  => 2,
    '_VERTICAL' => 1,
    'add' => Array(
        'type' => 'script',
        'title' => 'Create new record',
        'icon' => 'add.gif',
        'params' => Array(
            'table'=>'myTable',
            'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
            'setValue' => 'prepend'
        ),
        'module' => array(
            'name' => 'wizard_add',
        )
    ),
),
```

in TYPO3 9 this does not work anymore. I the manual i cannot find anything to the TCA wizards anymore since version 8.

Are they gone, or is there an other way to achive the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate to [`fieldControl` used since TYPO3v8](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Deprecation-79440-TcaChanges.html#wizard-list) and newer.

```php
'fieldControl' => [
    'addRecord' => [
        'disabled' => false,
        'options' => [
            'table' => 'myTable',
            'setValue' => 'prepend',
        ],
    ],
],
```